# How to trigger NMI in VMware

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere

Our physical Linux servers have an ILO board that may be used to create an non-maskable interrupt. This easily triggers the creation of a kernel dump in case the server is unresponsive. How can this be done in a virtual machine?

In order to debug unresponsible Linux servers, we currently trigger the kernel dump of virtual machines via key combination ALT+SysRq+c. However it does not work via terminal server connection - especially with different keyboard mappings and various client configurations.

To straighten the process, we would like to use the API or to use a native Vmware method that triggers a NMI on hung machines.

Is this possible?

Comment: I hope you don't have to use this often!

Comment: Not very often but its absolutely needed in order to receive vendor support. The alternative would be to just reboot the VM but that would not solve the root cause.

Answer (score 3):

On the actual ESXi host, logged in as root run this;

```
/sbin/vmdumper <world_id> nmi
```

where  is that of the VM you want to NMI.

Comment: Thanks. I will check that with a test machine. After searching for vmdumper I also found more related information in this article that looks promising: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2011/03/04/devil-s-in-the-details.aspx